# Meaning of "hot" in "hot-spiced"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "But the large Jimmies go into baskets to be sold alive to the crab
>   houses offering the freshly steamed **hot-spiced** hard crabs so
>   popular around the Bay."
>
> William Warner, Beautiful Swimmers: Waterman, Crabs and the Chesapeake
>   Bay

How can I interpret “hot” in “hot-spiced”? Does it mean the spices added are hot (temperature)? Or does it mean crabs are hot (temperature)? Or does “hot” here mean spicy?

> spiced
>
> Flavoured with spice. (Oxford Dictionary)
>
> https://www.lexico.com/definition/spiced

Comment: I'd say they explicitly write *hot-spiced*, so it is not confused with anything. Neither with hot temperature, nor with mildy-spiced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as describing temperature, "heat" is used in English to describe the strength of spice in food - particularly chilli spice.

For example, on menus in 'Indian' restaurants, curries are often rated on a scale that goes from *mild*, to *medium* (or sometimes "*medium-hot*"), to *hot*.

Because both types of heat can describe food it *can* cause some confusion - if someone says "*this chilli is hot*" you may have to ask them if they mean it has a high temperature or if it is very spicy. Usually, context makes it clear.

In your example, they have hyphenated the words "hot-spiced" to make it clear that "hot" is referring to the degree of spice. If it were "hot, spiced crabs" then it would more likely be that they are *served* at a hot temperature.

Comment: FWIW, if you are in Maryland, the dominant version of this "hot spice" mix is known by the brand name "Old Bay".